# Javascript image timer does not seem to be functioning properly

Tags: javascript

This does not seem to be functioning properly:

```js
var images = [];
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle01.gif", timeout: 3600000});
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle02.gif", timeout: 16560000});
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle03.gif", timeout: 16560000});
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle04.gif", timeout: 16560000});
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle05.gif", timeout: 16560000});
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/candle_end.gif", timeout: 16560000});

//Set the interval with the first element
var x = 0;
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
  changeImage()
}, images[x].timeout);

function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById('candle').src = images[x].src;
  if (x < images.length) {
    x += 1;
  } else {
    x = 0;
  }
  timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    changeImage()
  }, images[x].timeout);
}
```

The timer works okay if the time is in seconds, but I need it to be in hours. Specifically, one hour for the first image and the rest split over the 24 hour period. Could it be that the seconds count is too long? Does it HAVE to be in Milliseconds?

Comment: "*This does not seem to be functioning properly:*" is not very explicatory. What do you expect and what goes wrong ?

Comment: No, it will not work, anyway... whenever page is reloaded (and i guess that user will not wait 24 hours) your script and timer is at the start... you will have to find different way to solve this... e.g, by using date methods... if goal is to show different picture in specific time of the day....

Comment: The only error is in `if (x<images.length)`. It should be `if (x<images.length-1)` since you increment the counter aftewards and the indexing is 0-based.

Comment: @sinisake, no just open once then leave the window open and let the "candle" burn down.

Comment: @sinisake could be that it is used offline on a presentation screen or something. He did not mention how it will be used.

Comment: @Gaby meaning it stops at the second image.

Comment: Oddly the jfiddle seems to throw an error: `}//]]>` is all that shows.

Comment: @SeanRawles a) is that the only script in the page ? b) if not then the `x` might be altered by other code since it is global. c) does the page stay open for the required hours without reload ?

Comment: Gaby this is the page URL:

http://mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/mini-candle-popup.php The requirement was that the image be in it's own window, start from the time it is "lit" and then burn down over a 24 hour period. I had a very good working all timer javascript, but they wanted it to be 2 hours, then 22 hours for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the function requires miliseconds, but you can have that conversion logic in your function:

```
function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById('candle').src = images[x].src;
       if (x<images.length) {
         x+=1;
       }else{
         x=0;
  }
  var milisecondTimeout = 1000 * 3600 * images[x].timeout;
  timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {changeImage()}, milisecondTimeout);
  }
```

And then you could push your images with hours instead of miliseconds:

```
images.push({src: "http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/Candle_images/Candle01.gif", timeout: 1});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why would it work, since you changed nothing ? just move the calculation elsewhere..

Comment: The question is asking to have hours... can you explain the negative vote?... the image array in my solution is now pushing hours... and the conversion is done within the function. So the array can have hours instead of long numbers, that is the initial request... @GabyakaG.Petrioli can you explain the vote down? Check the initial question... he mentioned that he wanted to push array with hours, which my code does. Please scroll all the way to the right on the second piece of code

Comment: It does help :) Evertything helps. Being helpful is great and I appreciate EVERY answer as I muddle through my learning of this incredibly difficult subject at my age.

Comment: @DavidEspino (*not my downvote*) but the initial question is "***This does not seem to be functioning properly***" The applied milliseconds given in the OP is correct (*precalculated*).

Comment: oh ok ... :( sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` uses a 32 bit int to store the delay so the maximum value possible is 2147483647.

So that gives you a maximum of 596.52 hours which is more than enough for what you need.

But yes, it has to be in milliseconds because that's the only unit `setTimeout()` accepts.

Unless you add conversion logic before sending the values to the function.